# Spring Boot - Rest API not working on LAN

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, networking

I have a simple Spring Boot application with a Rest API. It only accepts a simple GET request and returns a string.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getTest() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

In my application.properties I have only one property set: `server.port=29090`

If I use my browser on the same device to test this, it works as expected. I go to `http://localhost:29090/test`, and it shows only the word `test`.

If I use another device in the same network for the GET request, going to `http://192.168.1.2:29090/test`, there is no response and eventually the request times out. The server is running Windows, I checked the firewall and there is indeed an inbound rule specifying port 29090 is allowed for TCP, on private, public and domain networks.

I suspected router misconfigurations, so I started up wireshark on the server machine to check network traffic. I do see the TCP SYN requests coming from the other device toward port 29090, so the router is working correctly, but there is no SYN-ACK reply from the server machine.

I did add the `@CrossOrigin` annotation in the code above after some googling, to see if that was the issue, but the problem persists. What could be the issue?

Comment: imho it will be still problem with open/closed ports on your machine - maybe you are receiving requests but probably host settings do not allow request inside. However you did not provide any info about your machine/OS etc and even if you would I'm not an expert when it comes to servers... :)

Comment: Are you able to access http://192.168.1.2:29090/test on the server?

Comment: @slauth I tried that, it doesn't work from the server either.
@ m.antkowicz I mentioned, the server is running on windows and I did check the firewall configuration

Comment: If it doesn't work from the server, it won't work from clients as well. Check on which address your app is listening (using something like `ss`/`netstat`).

Comment: @slauth I checked netstat, and it is there. From what I remember local applications can be accessed only with localhost or 127.0.0.1, but here is the output:

`TCP    0.0.0.0:29090          PC753:0                LISTENING
 [java.exe]`

Comment: `netstat` output looks good too me. And you're sure that your server really has the IP `192.168.1.2` assigned?

Comment: @slauth Yes, I checked in ipconfig, and the fact that I see the TCP requests in wireshark confirms it.